# Iterate in django views

Tags: python, django

I have problem with iteration all over the list in django views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import condition
import time
import roundrobin


STATES = [
    "hello",
    "world"
]

get_roundrobin = roundrobin.basic(STATES)

def test(request):
    for i in get_roundrobin():
        return HttpResponse(i)
```

Django answers me only first symbol of the each element of the STATES list, I mean django return  "h" then "w" instead "hello" then "world", how to fix it?

Upd: By the way inside of the roundrobin library, there the next code:

```
from itertools import cycle


def basic(dataset):
    iterator = cycle(dataset)

    def get_next():
        a = next(iterator)
        print(a)
        return a

    return get_next
```

All is correct, it answers like "hello" then "world".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `get_roundrobin` returns a string and then you are iterating through a list which returns only first character at a time, Try this

```py
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, HttpResponse
from django.views.decorators.http import condition
import time
import roundrobin


STATES = [
    "hello",
    "world"
]

get_roundrobin = roundrobin.basic(STATES)

def test(request):
    return HttpResponse(get_roundrobin())
```

> Now test will return `'hello'` then `'world'` then `'hello'` and so on...

Comment: Happy to help, accept the answer if this solves your question :)